# Where to put WebSockets in with 3-layer, Clean Architecture?

Tags: node.js, oop, websocket, socket.io, architecture

I see that proper express node apps structured with three layers:

- networking/route controlling
- application/services
- data storage

But I am unsure how to apply this to web sockets (particularly using Socket.io library in TypeScript Node).

Imagine a real-time multiplayer game. The socket events from the client to the server would obviously, like a typical REST server, be intercepted and processed at the controller layer, then passed to the application layer to cause the game engine to take respective effects.

But given that it is real-time multiplayer, the game engine also needs the ability to initiate contact with clients, unprovoked, to notify them of game updates. This implies that web socket components (the setup of handlers, calls to socket related functions, ...) need to exist at the application layer as well.

To avoid putting web-socket stuff both in the networking layer and the application layer, my current thoughts are to create a Gateway abstraction to sit between the networking and application layer, responsible both for allowing the network layer to gain access to application level components and for allowing the application layer to gain access to network level components, with all of the web socket functions / classes existing at the network level.

Any corrections, explanations, examples, and design patterns would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all [Clean Architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) traditionally is split into 4 layers rather than 3:

[image]

So since you don't provide the actual dependencies graph for your 3 layers it seems that you have more of traditional 3-layers architecture.

Either way both for Clean Architecture and your defined layers it makes much more sense to place the web sockets stuff on the outmost layer and somehow inject it into corresponding service/application, i.e. follow the standard DI/IoC patterns.

Not fluent with Node/TypeScript so can't recommend the most appropriate/idiomatic technique but the general idea would be to define some contract (interface) for let's call it "notifier" and pass it's implementation to corresponding application/service during construction (contract/interface can be defined on the app/service layer and the implementation on the networking/route controlling). This will provide the standard benefits of such approach - decoupling the logic from implementation and used frameworks (for example you can inject test implementations for unit testing or change to some other mechanism for the notifications - maybe in future you will want to introduce intermediate message bus or something like it).

Comment: *"First of all Clean Architecture traditionally is split into 4 layers rather than 3:"*
You can overlay the 3-layered architecture schema ontop of the 4 layered Clean Architecture, with Presentation { UI, Presenter }, Domain { Use Cases, Entities }, and Data { Repository, Data Source }. See [this diagram](https://imgur.com/a/vK3dDiu)